# UILabel with two different fontColor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitextview

How can I have one UILabel with two different font color/type? I don't think this is possible to do, if not, then what is the closest way to do this? My solution now is to use two UILabel and then put one of the UILabel on top of the other one and put a spacing/indentation for the second UILabel for the text to start. However the issue is that the indentation is misaligned. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsattributedstring_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Check out [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel).

Comment: I think one issue I am facing with this NSAttributedString is that I can't seem to get the width and height correctly when using [commentsText sizeWithFont:self.commentsText_.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.commentsText_.frameWidth, 1000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip]; because I have one word which is bold and have a larger font size

Comment: Use `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints` to determine the size correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) is probably what you want, but another possibility is to use a `UIWebView` with HTML and CSS.